# Trying to use dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier without inheriting from UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to basically copy this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9eFo2fRCdU

into an existing project but its view controller inherits from UICollecitonview where as my existing projects one inherits from UIViewController is there a way around this? here is the code im trying to get to work:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionViewCell *)
    collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Cell * aCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    aCell.myLabel .text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];

    return aCell;



}
```

Comment: I think it would work if you implemented the `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol.

Comment: Yes, set your controller as the data source and delegate for the collection view, and then that method will be called.

Comment: im extremely new to ios could you explain what you mean by that

Answer (score 0):

You can use UICollectionView in the view controller of your choice.  It is necessary to alloc/init:

```
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 100.0f, 525.0f, 500.0f) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    [collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [collectionView setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    [collectionView setAllowsSelection:NO];
    [collectionView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
    [collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self.view addSubview:collectionView];
```

Then, you need to implement the usual delegate/datasource methods.  Something like the above.